# the round corner of uiview does not look so great,uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I round the corner of my view using :

```
self.instructionView.layer.borderColor          =   [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
self.instructionView.layer.borderWidth          =   .5;
self.instructionView.layer.cornerRadius         =   5;
```

and What I am getting is the corner is rounded but the corner does not look so great. Please look at the pic for your info

[image]

How can i do or are there other ways to fix this issue.

Comment: Time to buy a Retina device?

Comment: no i dont think so. cuz I am also installing on the iphone5 and  the corner is still not so great.

Comment: What did you expect from a line width of 0.5 points?

Comment: @Till :just wanna show the border of the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the 1/2 pixel problem.

There's no way to draw 1/2 pixel, so Core Graphics will use anti-aliasing and to fake it and that's the effect you are seeing on the screen.

Consider increasing the border size (or buy a Retina device as H2CO3 suggested in the comments :P )